# Crystal Reports WHERE clause

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal Reports I want to write a formula that goes something like this

```
SUM(Sales) WHERE Department = 'Food'
```

How should I write this query in Crystal Reports?

I want this formula on a sub-report. I am aware that the `WHERE` clause is not usable in CR.

Answer (score 0):

In the sub-report open the Select Expert and add following condition:

- Column `Department` **is equal to** *"Food"*

Then create a sum for the column `Sales`.